# Manjaro displays "Failed to load Kernel Modules" on boot but still boots

Tags: kernel-modules, manjaro

So I've installed Manjaro on my sandisk SSD. Every time I boot up, before the login screen when the system boots and show a lot of text on the screen, I see 1/2/3 (I don't know the exact amount) times "Failed to load Kernel Modules"

I'm not sure what it tries to load, because the system boots correctly. I want to know what it tries to load but can't and how to solve it.

Is there any way I can find the exact kernel modules it cannot load?

Answer (score 1):

You can use:

```
journalctl -b
```

To read the boot log.

```
journalctl -b | grep kernel | grep load
```

should give you an insight of what is going on.